# Conflict between perfect forwarding constructor and copy constructor in class hierarchy

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor, sfinae, perfect-forwarding

I recently encountered a problem while trying to implement a class hierarchy with perfect forwarding constructors.
Consider the following example:

```
struct TestBase {
  template<typename T>
  explicit TestBase(T&& t) : s(std::forward<T>(t)) {} // Compiler refers to this line in the error message

  TestBase(const TestBase& other) : s(other.s) {}

  std::string s;
};

struct Test : public TestBase {
  template<typename T>
  explicit Test(T&& t) : TestBase(std::forward<T>(t)) {}

  Test(const Test& other) : TestBase(other) {}
};
```

When I try to compile the code I get the following error:

> Error 3   error C2664: 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>::basic_string(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const Test' to 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &'

My understanding is that the compiler treats the perfect forwarding constructor as a better math than the copy constructor. See for example [Scott Meyers: Copying Constructors in C++11](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.de/2012/10/copying-constructors-in-c11.html) . In other implementations without a class hierarchy I could disable the perfect forwarding constructor from being a copy constructor through SFINAE. See for example [Martinho Fernandes: Some pitfalls with forwarding constructors](http://rmartinho.github.com/2012/06/05/is_related.html). When I try to apply the mentioned solution to this example I still cannot compile with the same error message.

I think one possible solution would be to avoid the perfect forwarding, take the parameters by value in the constructors and than move from them to the class variables.

So my question is if there are some other solutions to this problem or if perfect forwarding in not possible in such a case?

**Update:**
It turned out that my question is easy to misunderstand. So I will try to clarify my intentions and the context a bit.

- The code is complete like posted in the question. There are no other objects created or functions called. The error appeared while trying to compile the posted example.
- The purpose of having the perfect forwarding constructor is for member initialization and *not* to have some kind of extra copy constructor. The reason here is to save some object copies when initializing members with temporary objects (as proposed in talks by Scott Meyers)
- Unfortunately as it turned out perfect forwarding constructor can conflict with other overloaded constructors (in this example with the copy constructors).
- Like the answers and comments to this question suggested: Possible solutions here would be to introduce explicit casts or having separate non-templated constructors (i.e. regarding the example having two constructors with parameters `const string&` and `string&&` respectively).

Comment: Might it be that you wrote something like `std::string(test)` instead of `std::string(test.s)`? Please show us the line 130 of main.cc

Comment: You wrote `s(std::forward<T>(t))` instead of `s(std::forward<T>(t).s)`.

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to mix overloads and forwarding templates. I'd make a single constructor from `string` and add a forwarding `make_test` *function* template.

Comment: @Andrey Sorry I should have highlighted the origin of the error message. The line number 130 in main.cc refers to the perfect forwarding constructor in TestBase. I will edit my example...

Comment: @avakar The parameter t should not be a object of the Test class but instead some kind of string (i.e. std::string or cont char*). I don't want the perfect forwarding constructor to be a copy constructor so I think I should not add an `.s`

Comment: @KerrekSB Consider Test is a class. In this case how would you handle the parameter assignment in the constructor while trying to avoid unnecessary copies. Would you recommend to take the string by value and move from it to the member?

Comment: @mkh: I would only give `Test` concrete constructors that accept the relevant data, and leave all additional implicit constructions to a helper function. Like `make_shared` and `make_unique`.

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal complete example that reproduces the problem? In particular, the `main` function.

Comment: @avakar Please believe that is all there really is. It is just the code I posted in a .cc file and a empty main function. I don't call any functions or create objects. If I try to compile the file I get the error message.

Comment: @KerrekSB Ok - thanks for your explanation. I'm still interested in solutions without any helper functions like Yakk idea. Thanks alot!

Comment: @mkh: The problem is that you end up with a very dirty design. *Some* of your constructors will require a copy of the object itself, and some others will randomly directly initialize some of your class members. Sure, you can hack it up to work, but it'll be a nightmare to use.

Comment: Oh, I get it now, Yakk is correct in their analysis.

Comment: And if all you want is to construct from a string, why not just have an lvalue and an rvalue reference to string constructor? There's no need for the template.

Comment: @KerrekSB I guess your right - I guess I will rethink my design and follow your recommendation. But I'm also interested in the solutions to get some better understanding whats going on.

Comment: @KerrekSB Also I mainly came up with the implementation because of Scott Meyers recent talks about perfect forwarding. He recommends to use perfect forwarding for constructors and setters. I guess in scenarios with overloading this is not always the optimal solution.

Comment: @mkh: I think you're confusing something. You want forwarding when you *call* a constructor, not when you *define* one.

Comment: @KerrekSB That's true but if I understood Scott Meyers talks correctly than perfect forwarding constructors can save you some parameter copies if you want to assign to member variables. I was thinking about constructors similarly to perfect forwarding setters. If you want perfect forwarding for member assignment than you also have to define your constructors/setters as so, right?! I think perfect forwarding constructors are a nice idea if you are careful with overloads. For example a perfect forwarding constructor with two parameters would be no problem in my example.

Comment: @mkh Actualy KerrekSB is kind of right about 'a bad idea to mix overloads and forwarding templates'. The thing you do with a templated constructor taking `&&` parameters also handles the `&` parameters. You can check Scott Meyers' Universal References in C++11 video at channel9. If you really want to treat `&` constructor and `&&` constructor differently. Then you can consider making `&&` constructor non-template. e.g. `explicit TestBase(TestBase&& t) : s(std::move(t)) {}`

Comment: @zahir I think my question is easy to misunderstand, unfortunately. The intention of my perfect forwarding constructor is for member initialization **not** for copy construction. So I don't see where your example could fit in, sorry. I think KerrekSB is correct that having two constructors for member initialization (one `const string&` and one `string&&`) would be more explicit and easy to follow. In general I still think that perfect forwarding constructors are nice for member initialization, but be careful with overloads. I watched that video btw - thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `Test(const Test& other) : TestBase(other) {}` to `Test(const Test& other) : TestBase(static_cast<TestBase const&>(other)) {}`

The 2nd `Test` constructor is calling TestBase, and there are two possibilities.  One of them takes anything, the other takes a TestBase.  But you are passing a Test to it -- the "anything" matches better.  By explicitly casting to a TestBase const&, we should be able to get the right one to match.

Another possibility might involve how Test is constructed -- maybe what you passed in matched the template constructor to Test instead?  We can test this other possibility by removing the template constructor from Test and seeing if the error goes away.

If that is the case, why wouldn't the technique you linked (to disable the Test template constructor when the type deduced matches Test) work?

Comment: Your solution compiles without errors. Could there be any possible side effects while applying your solution? Usually I like to be a little bit careful when silencing errors/warnings with casts.

Comment: The cast in question is a safe one.  I cast a Foo const& into a FooBase const& -- something that you wanted to do implicitly, but the compiler preferred your template constructor that accepts everything.  I made explicit what you wanted to implicitly happen...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. One more question: If I now add a move constructor to Test like this: `Test(Test&& other) : TestBase(std::move(other)) {}`. I get the same error message again. Do you possibly also have a solution for this situation? Tanks alot!

Comment: You are calling `TestBase(Test&&)` in your sample code.  Do you see where?  Now, looking at ONLY the definition of `TestBase`, which ctor will that call?

Comment: +1, that's a really subtle thing. Took me some staring at the monitor to realize what's going on.

Comment: @Yakk Alright I guess I got your point. But than consider I also add a move constructor to TestBase like `TestBase(TestBase&& other) : s(std::move(other.s)) {}`. If I understand right that should be a better match than the perfect forwarding constructor right?! But still same error. Sorry for being sticky - just trying to understand without getting more confused.

Comment: You have a template ctor.  It will snarf many things that would otherwise be implicitly cast. If you get such an error because you are relying on any implicit casts, make that cast explicit with a static cast.

Answer (score 1):

Let's have a closer look at the error message.

`std::basic_string<...>::basic_string(const std::basic_string<...> &) :`

That means it applies to a copy constructor of `std::string`

`cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const Test' to 'const std::basic_string<..> &`

Indeed, there's no way to convert from `Test` to `std::string`. However, `Test` has a string member, namely, `std::string s;`.

Conclusion: it looks like you forgot to add `.s` at that place. Probably, it is in `s(std::forward<T>(t))`.

Another possible reason is that the 1st overload of the constructor was picked instead of the 2nd for copy-constructing an instance of `Test`.

Comment: I don't think I forgot the `.s`. My idea was that the parameter t is itself some kind of string which I want to forward to the member. For example a const char* or an std::string.

Comment: @mkh: Then it means that it happened somehow that T is not a string but `Test`.

Comment: Than my question would be how can I make the compiler stop thinking that T could possibly be a Test. I don't create any objects or call any functions.

Comment: @Andrey yep -- it appears that ctor 2 in `Test` ends up calling ctor 1 in `TestBase` "unintentionally".  Then they try to convert a Test into a string, which fails.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work and it uses no explicit casts:

```
struct Test : public TestBase {
  private: 
  static TestBase const& toBase(const Test& o) { return o; }

  public:
  template <typename T>
  explicit Test(T&& t) : TestBase(std::forward<T>(t)) {}

  Test(const Test& other) : TestBase(toBase(other)) {} 
};
```