# Template neglects const (why?)

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, constants, default-constructor

Does somebody know, why this compiles??

```
template< typename TBufferTypeFront, typename TBufferTypeBack = TBufferTypeFront>
class FrontBackBuffer{

public:


  FrontBackBuffer(
    const TBufferTypeFront  front, 
    const TBufferTypeBack back):    ////const reference  assigned to reference???
     m_Front(front),
     m_Back(back)
  {
  };

  ~FrontBackBuffer()
  {};

  TBufferTypeFront m_Front;       ///< The front buffer
  TBufferTypeBack m_Back;         ///< The back buffer

};

int main(){
    int b;
    int a;
    FrontBackBuffer<int&,int&> buffer(a,b); //
    buffer.m_Back = 33;
    buffer.m_Front = 55;
}
```

I compile with GCC 4.4. Why does it even let me compile this? Shouldn't there be an error that I cannot assign a const reference to a non-const reference?

Comment: Top level const-volatile qualifiers are ignored in function signatures.

Comment: AFAIK const reference does not exists. You can only have reference to const object (`const int&` is valid, `int& const` does not exists). However this does not resolve your issue here...

Comment: Why are the names of the parameters to the constructor prefixed with `m`?  Doesn't that stand for member?  And isn't its purpose to disambiguate member objects from function local and global objects?

Comment: m_ stands for member yes, and yes its an error :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the code to do what you want it to do, it would have to read:

```
  FrontBackBuffer(
    typename std::remove_reference<TBufferTypeFront>::type const&  m_front, 
    typename std::remove_reference<TBufferTypeBack>::type const& m_back):    ////const reference  assigned to reference???
    m_Front(m_front),
    m_Back(m_back)
  {
  };
```

which has the added "feature" that it turns other types into const references when used to construct `FrontBackBuffer`.

Now this isn't perfect.  This prevents temporary arguments to `FrontBackBuffer` from being moved, and passes even small cheap to copy types (like `char`) by reference instead of by value.  There are standard C++0x techniques to do this that are a bit awkward to write if you care.

Comment: Would be very interested how that is possible? Thanks for the help!! Was very helpful!

Comment: The technique is called "perfect forwarding".  There is a stack overflow tag for it.  I'd advise reading up on it a bunch before trying it: odds are you don't need to know how to do it yet.  Here is a question I answered where someone demonstrates a use of perfect forwarding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13160826/conflict-between-perfect-forwarding-constructor-and-copy-constructor-in-class-hi -- read these for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perfect-forwarding

Answer (score 13):

The thing is that if type `T` is `int&`, then the type `const T` is not `const int&`, but `int & const`. The illegal top-level const on a reference is ignored in template substitutions and typedef results.

If, on the other hand `T` is `const int`, then `T&` is `const int&`

Comment: @Gabriel, not so much if you know how to pronounce types. const int & is pronounced as "reference to const int", whereas the illegal int & const would be "const reference to (non-const) int". So if T is "reference to int", then const T is "const reference to int". If T is const int then T& is reference to const int. Hope this was clear

Comment: Thanks, so the strange thing is that T = reference to int = int& yields then "const T" = const int &     -> where the const gets ignored and there stands   int &  .... thats not intuitive isnt it?

the understanding comes from a normal code like "const int & a = 2"  which is basically the wrong form (right to left: reference to int const = reference to const int)...

Answer (score 5):

When TypeBufferFront is `int&`, `const TBufferTypeFront` is equivalent to `int& const`, where the const is ignored during template substitution, since all references are constant, even if what they refer to is not.

So, when instantiated with `int&`, your constructor is effectively `FrontBackBuffer(int&, int&)`, which works as given.

This is an example of why many people will use `T const` instead of `const T`, to make it clearer how the substitution occurs, as well as allow them to read the cv-qualifiers from right to left.

Comment: So can I understand this as :  *const* int & const  -> and the *const* gets ingnored?

Comment: @Gabriel:  No, the point is that if it were legal, a `const int& const` is the same as a `int const& const` a constant reference to a constant integer.  During template substitution, `int const& const` (which is not legal) is reduced to `int const&` (which is legal).

Answer (score 0):

`FrontBackBuffer::m_Front` is of type `TBufferTypeFront` which translates to `int&` in your template instantiation. There is nothing wrong with assigning to an `int&`.

Comment: There is something wrong with binding an `int&` to an `const int&`.  Gabriel thinks that the parameters to the constructor are of type `const int&`, and that's why the question.